# Updating embedded chart with app script messes up vertical axis formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am updating a chart in Google Sheets every day when the data is modified on the sheet. I had to adjust the vertical axis to fit the data, but then I ran into an issue where the chart automatically sets the vertical axis format to `MM/DD/YY` instead of a decimal (e.g. 1.41). I saw someone mentioning using `vAxis.format` to update the number format, but it doesn't work. I've tried doing inline `.setOption` and the below setting several options at once, and neither one works. Is there a way to prevent the update from changing the format or to update the format?

```html
function updateCharts() {

 let report = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email Report");
 let chartMin = report.getRange(3,11).getValue();
 let chartMax = report.getRange(4,11).getValue();

 let chart = report.getCharts()[0];
 let chartOptions = {
    maxValue: chartMax,
    minValue: chartMin,
    minorGridlines: {count: 0},
    format: 'decimal'
  };

  let chartMod = chart.modify()
    .setOption('vAxis', chartOptions)
    .build();
  report.updateChart(chartMod);
  
}
```

Here's a copy of the spreadsheet containing the raw data and the chart: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-m7TlB8AlpW_q_tYrVbyVP9rSUmUnZ42_37Nu6bFVoo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: ````vAxis.format```` is not a valid property as per the documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-line-chart-builder. However, the default format is ````From Source Data````, which always takes the format of the first column.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, you can file this at https://issuetracker.google.com/